# Performance difference passing complex object to javsacript function vs single var?

Tags: javascript, performance, object

Consider a function that acts on one element of complex object I'm passing around. I can write it as:

```
function foo(object) {
  bar(object.item)
}
```

or

```
function foo(item) {
  bar(item);
}
```

If I have the option, is there any performance benefit to passing just the single element of the object to a function vs passing the whole object and pulling out the pieces I need?

I.e., is it more efficient to call:

```
 foo(object);
```

and pass along the entire object let foo deal with, or

```
 foo(object.item);
```

which only passes the single item?

---

Update: It looks like the terminology I could not find until the comments arrived is whether Javascript is **pass-by-reference** or **pass-by-value**.

As objects are passed by reference in Javascript (with some important caveats), it should make no difference how big the object I'm passing is.

Interesting reading:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-by-reference-vs-by-value-d49139beb1c4

Comment: I can’t imagine much of any difference, but why not test it yourself and find out?

Comment: Keep in mind that objects are just reference values. There is absolutely no difference between passing "big" objects and passing "small" objects, if that was what you were trying to compare.

Comment: Make sure that `foo` takes the parameters it needs and nothing else. Favour maintainability over microoptimisations.

Comment: @Ry- I'm not prematurely optimizing, I'm trying to understand how things work. Looks like Bergi provides the key here.

Comment: What type is `object.item`? If it is a large string, that could make a difference, as strings are pass-by-value.

Comment: @jotaen No, strings are implemented as reference values as well - just immutable ones. There is no copying of string contents involved when calling a function or assigning a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object property access is a *little bit* more expensive than plain value access. (warning, the following snippet will *block* your browser for a bit, depending on your computer's specs:)

```js
(() => {
  const obj = { foo: 'bar' };

  const t0 = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
    obj.foo;
  }
  const t1 = performance.now();

  const { foo } = obj;
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
    foo;
  }
  const t2 = performance.now();
  console.log('Object property access: ' + (t1 - t0));
  console.log('Variable access: ' + (t2 - t1));
})();
```

The difference is tiny, but it's there. When you have `obj.prop`, the interpreter first has to look up what `obj` refers to, and then it has to look up the `prop` property on `obj` to get to the value. So, it makes sense that it's a bit easier when the value you're looking for is already in a standalone variable - all that's necessary to get to it is for the interpreter to look up that variable.

But, for the example you mention, *no matter what*, you'll be doing one object lookup, and one plain value lookup:

```
foo(object); // 1 variable lookup
function foo(object) {
  bar(object.item) // 1 object property lookup
}

// vs

foo(object.item); // 1 object property lookup
function foo(item) {
  bar(item); // 1 variable lookup
}
```

It would be different if `foo` used the `.item` property *more than once*. For example, if `foo` had:

```
foo(object); // 1 variable lookup
function foo(object) {
  bar(object.item) // 1 object property lookup
  baz(object.item) // 1 object property lookup
}
```

that would require *two* object property lookups, which means it would be (very slightly) more efficient to pass the `item` alone.

All this said, the difference *really is minuscule*. As you can see with the snippet, it requires *one billion* iterations (at least on my machine) to reliably see a difference, and even then, the improvement is only ~5-10% or so, at least for me on Chrome. It's not something worth worrying about in 99% of situations. Code readability is more important.

Comment: "*it would be (very slightly) more efficient to pass the item alone.*" - or just introduce a local variable for it when used multiple times.

Comment: TBH I'm surprised that the [compiler didn't eat your microbenchmark for breakfast](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html) and optimised that loop to a no-op.

Comment: Got it. So the heavy book (object) sits on the shelf, and the code talks about it and occasionally looks up something in the book, but does not actually hand the book from one function to another. The lookup takes a certain (small) amount of time no matter when it happens.

Comment: @Trees4theForest Sure, though keep in mind that there's no difference in passing around one reference vs passing around another, eg referencing `foo` should take the same amount of time no matter whether `foo` is a boolean or a large object.